# How to implement offline sync in java MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, data-analysis, symmetricds

I plan to implement offline sync on my java application.

When machine is offline then use local DB data and restrict some feature like create/delete. I Got some idea after find a lot of search from google. But, still not clear exactly.

My doubts are

1. Is symmetric DS or MySQL replication can help my scenario ?
2. Sync from server every minute through web service (for server to local and local to server DB data)

Comment: What does it mean offline? When the application is not running or when there's no network?

Comment: @BorisPavlović 

when there's no network

Comment: What are the two databases that should be synced? Is there a network between?

Comment: One is server : It can store multiple client DB data (server differentiate data by client id) 
Another one is client: It can store local data only

Is there a network between : Yes

Comment: How can they sync if they're offline? If there's no network connection between sync is impossible

Comment: Ya that is my question.
How to offline sync ?

Comment: @BorisPavlović
What are the two databases that should be synced? Is there a network between? 

Server runs on cloud and clients run locally

Comment: If databases are not having network connection there's no way of establishing communication nor sync

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second question is positive. Symmetricds can sync every minute or more often if necessary. It's a configuration parameter

Comment: Did you mean "Sync from server every minute through web service" is best ?

Comment:  I did mean the second question